# Android: how to read properly with Realm from background threads?

Tags: android, multithreading, realm

This is the method

```
public static List<User> getRecords(Context context) {
    Realm.init(context);
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    final RealmResults<Users> users = realm.where(Users.class).findAll();
    return realm.copyFromRealm(users);
}
```

If I click on menu item from an Activity, I get a list with all the stored objects. 
However, there is another thread created by a Service that periodically load the content from Realm.

```
  new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            List<User> users = LocalDb.getRecords(context);
        }
    }, 0, period);
```

In this case the list is empty. I did the trick of menu item to check it, so whenever I see that the thread is about to load I manually load from the menu item, then I see the thread with an empty list. If I click the menu item I can see the same list again, so it can be empty.

Comment: Please read the realm docs on how to properly configure a Realm and handle realm instance lifecycles. You are not doing it right

Comment: Could you tell me what is wrong? Perhaps I didn't pay enough attention on the docs, but I can't find the error

Comment: 1) you should not Realm.init() at random places in your code. 2) You should ***always make sure*** to close realm instances that you do not use anymore

Comment: You are experiencing version retention. Please read the documentation about the importance of closing local Realm instances. Also worth noting that unless you are trying to create an editable version of a RealmObject or want to detach it to serialize it with a reflection based parser (like GSON), relying on `copyFromRealm()` is ***semantically wrong***

Comment: Thanks to both of you, the error was the missing closure. Maybe they could write it in the first tutorial and subsequently  explain it. I was aware of the  difference between copy and the realm object but I needed for GSON (you confirmed it)

Comment: I recommend the pattern `try(Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) { return realm.copyFromRealm(...);` for this use case. But generally I say if you don't rely on RealmChangeListeners, then consider using immutable value classes as domain objects instead using autovalue.